# Edit value of cells in a specific column if a condition is not met using Excel VBA

Tags: vba, excel

I need a macro that will apply the below-mentioned formula in column J if the value of a cell in column C is "Hits_US" and the value of a cell in column D is "harry". Below is the formula

```
=((Column G*32)+(Column H*28)+300)/60
```

Please note that there will be other values in column J. So, only if the condition is met, the formula has to be applied.

I tried to do this in parts. I first tried to multiply the value in column G by 32. But it did not work.

```
For i = 1 To 10
    If Sheets(1).Range("C" & i).Value = "Hits_US" And Range("D" & i).Value <> "harry" Then
        Cells(i, 10) = Cells(i, 7) * 32
    End If
Next i
```

Comment: What do you mean by "did not work"? Perhaps you need a sheet reference everywhere.

Comment: Hi SJR! It's all in the same sheet - Sheet 1. When I ran the macro, the values did not change.

Comment: Are you sure Sheets(1) is the right sheet? It is not necessarily the same as a sheet called "Sheet 1".

Comment: Yeah! There's only one sheet in the workbook. So, it's the first sheet.

Comment: The problem is I'm unsure on how to apply the entire formula in column J if the condition is met. So, if you could suggest something to solve that, it would be really helpful!

Comment: OK, have you stepped through the code to check what is happening? Are you sure both conditions are met on at least one row - perhaps you have a blank or trailing spaces.

Comment: I did! I wasn't able to find any blanks or trailing spaces.. I also checked for  the conditions..

Comment: Have suggested code below, but hard to know why your code above doesn't work as nothing is obviously wrong with it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to avoid a loop

```
Sheets(1).Range("J1:J10").Formula = "=IF(AND(C1=""Hits_US"",D1=""Harry""),(G1*32+H1*28+300)/60,"""")"
```

For all rows in J, based on how many entries are in column C

```
With Sheets(1)
    .Range("J1:J" & .Range("C" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row).Formula = "=IF(AND(C1=""Hits_US"",D1<>""Harry""),(G1*32+H1*28+300)/60,"""")"
End With
```

Comment: Just spotted something else. Your code refers to "<>Harry" but your post says column D should be Harry - you need to make up your mind!

Comment: It works perfect, SJR! Thank you! And thanks for finding the miss! I've corrected it now! One more doubt - My sheet will have more than 10 rows and this formula has to be applied for all the rows in the sheet. I tried changing the code from Range("J1:J10") to Range (J:J), but the data remained the same. Any idea on how to sort this?

Comment: @SJR- I just faced a problem! When there's Harry in column D, the formula gets applied in column J and the cell turns blank. Is there a way we could avoid this? I don't want the formula to be applied if the value in col D is Harry.. Thanks much!

Comment: Have you changed the "<>" to "="?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to leave a formula in cells then I'd go with R1C1 notation:

```
Sheets(1).Range("J1:J10").FormulaR1C1 = "=IF(AND(RC3=""Hits_US"",RC4=""harry""),(RC7*32+RC8*28+300)/60,"""")"
```

While if you want to leave only the formula results then you have to possibilities:

1. have formulas do the math and then leave only values

   ```
   With Sheets(1).Range("J1:J10")
       .FormulaR1C1 = "=IF(AND(RC3=""Hits_US"",RC4=""harry""),(RC7*32+RC8*28+300)/60,"""")"
       .Value = .Value
   End With
   ```
2. have VBA do the math and write its results directly

   ```
   With Sheets(1)
       For i = 1 To 10
           If .Range("C" & i).Value = "Hits_US" And .Range("D" & i).Value = "harry" Then
               .Cells(i, 10) = (.Cells(i, 7) * 32 + .Cells(i, 8) * 28 + 300) / 60
           End If
       Next
   End With
   ```

Comment: Thank you so much, DisplayName! I'll apply the codes you've suggested and let you know how it went!

Comment: Hi DisplayName! I tried to run the 2nd code that you had shared and it displays the following error in the line "If.Range("C"&i...  - Compile error:Invalid or unqualified reference. Please let me know if I missed something.